# AngularJS/HTML5 Nested Form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, angular-material

Im new to AngularJS and i have problem using HTML5 nested form validation properly.

I have 2 forms one is `mainFrm` *(parent form)* and the other is `stateFrm` *(a child form)*. I have problem validating each form on its own scope.

```
<form id="mainFrm" ng-submit="save()">

    <text-input form="mainFrm" required type="text">

    <form id="stateFrm" ng-submit="addState()">

        <input form="stateFrm" type="text">

        <!-- this wont add an item if input-text is empty--> 
        <!-- prompts html5 validation-->  
        <button form="stateFrm" type="submit">Add state to favorite</button>

        <!-- and a list of favorite states -->

    </form>

    <!-- (Will validate only the text-input of mainFrm if empty) -->
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**When doing this the submit button of stateFrm doesnt work. the ng-submit="" of that form wont trigger and there is no validation prompting when input is empty.**

Here is the working [DEMO](http://codepen.io/badcoder28/pen/xgXVoW)

> NOTE: I used angular-material design

Comment: What do you mean with "the submit button of stateFrm wont work properly"? What is the expected outcome vs actual outcome?

Comment: take stateFrm out of mainFrm

Comment: @Fissio i mean the button of stateFrm wont trigger the `vm.addItem(state)` the expected one is that there will be a validation if empty else add the item in the list

Comment: @MMK i cant do that for the sake of the user.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab Nested forms aren't allowed in HTML5. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536861/are-nested-forms-valid-in-html5

Comment: sad to say it is thanks for the information

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab, added a working example without nested forms, with the same layout

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab what happend there. (for the sake of the user)

Comment: @MMK your idea is fine as Fissio

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab all matters you got the solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While nested forms aren't allowed in HTML5, you can separate the forms while keeping the same layout. Check the codepen here for a working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNrGrp

```
<form id="mainFrm" name="mainFrm" layout="column" ng-submit="vm.saveMain()">
  <md-input-container>
    <label for="name">Group name</label>
    <input type="text" required ng-model="group" />
  </md-input-container>
</form>

<form layout="column" name="stateFrm" layout-align="start" id="stateFrm" ng-submit="vm.addItem(state)">
  <md-input-container>
    <input required form="stateFrm" type="text" ng-model="state" aria-label="state item" placeholder="enter state"/>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-button form="stateFrm" class="md-raised" type="submit">Add state to favorite</md-button>

  <md-list>
    <md-subheader>Favorite States</md-subheader>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="state in vm.states | orderBy">
      <span class="md-body-1">{{ state }}</span>
    </md-list-item>
  </md-list>
</form>


<md-button form="mainFrm" class="md-raised md-primary" type="submit">Save Main</md-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [W3C HTML5 Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element), nested forms are not valid/allowed.